# Append Wordpress Shortcode to CSS Class

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to get a users earned badges to appear under a product comment. I have Woodiscuz to handle the comments, and meCRED for the badges.

The shortcode [mycred_my_badges user_id="author"] will show the post authors badges (tested and working on a regular page).

I have the following code:

```
$( ".wpc-comment-left" ).append( document.createTextNode("<?php echo json_encode(do_shortcode("[mycred_my_badges user_id="author"]")); ?>") );
```

Essentially my idea was to append the class of the comment (with avatar etc) with my shortcode, showing the badges. I have put this code into my javascript footer, but nothing seems to happen and no badges show.

Am I putting this code in the wrong place? Am I missing something really simple?

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
D

Comment: The correct way to make such a change is just to override the plugins comment template with a replicated template in your theme.

Comment: Daniel, any idea where i'd start on this? I'm not sure what code I need to change.

Comment: This link should explain it for you: https://wpdiscuz.com/docs/wpdiscuz-documentation/customization/custom-template-and-style/

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look :)

Comment: Daniel, i think that's actually a different plugin. I am using woodiscuz.

Comment: WooDiscuz – WooCommerce Comments?

Comment: That's the one :)

Comment: Try making a file called form.php in your theme, or try making it in your theme/comment-form/form.php

Comment: Looking through this file, i can't find the wpc-comment-left class. What am I looking for here?

Comment: It's in tpl-comment.php, at the bottom, try duplicating and editing that template.

Comment: Daniel, I have found where I need to put my code, and it shows some text in the right place. However, I think i'm having problems with my syntax... Here's the code: `$output .= '<?php echo do_shortcode("[mycred_my_badges user_id="author"]"); ?></div>';` Can you see what's wrong here? is it because I have 2 double quotes perhaps?

Comment: It's because of double quotes and using the php tag already inside of php, I've posted an answer that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the file where this is located, usually a good plugin will allow you to overwrite the template file.

Please find the file:

```
woodiscuz-woocommerce-comments/comment-form/tpl-comment.php
```

And try overwriting it by copy and pasting the code into:

```
themes/your-theme/comment-form/tpl-comment.php
```

And then find the place where "wpc-comment-left" is mention using search and replace that code section with:

```
<?php
$shortcode = '[mycred_my_badges user_id="author]';
$output = '<div id="wpc-comm-' . $unique_id . '" class="' . $wpc_comment_wrapper_class . ' ' . $parent_comment . ' wpc_comment_level-' . $depth . '">';
$output .= '<div id="wpc-comment-' . $comment->comment_ID . '" class="wpc-comment-left">' . $wpc_comm_author_avatar . do_shortcode($shortcode) . '</div>';
if (!$this->wpc_options_serialized->wpc_author_titles_show_hide) {
    $output .= '<div class="wpc-comment-label">' . $author_title . '</div>';
}?>
```

Unfortunately if you cannot override the file in your theme you will have to edit the core plugin file, which means should you update the plugin this change will be overwritten.

Comment: Hi Daniel. FINALLY it is working! :) Here is the code i used: `$shortcode = '[mycred_my_badges user_id="author"]';
        $output .= '<div class="comment-author-badges">' . do_shortcode($shortcode) .   '</div></div>';`. Very similar to yours, and i've marked your answer as correct for all of the help you have provided. Thank you very much, I was stuck on this for months (on and off) :). Note: Your 2nd line of code says shortcde - you're missing an o :)

Comment: No problem happy to help and fixed that minor spelling issue thanks :)

Comment: I am very grateful :)))